# SVG color updating script doesn't work on desktop but works on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript (and pretty much all my coding skills) knowledge is terrible but I'm working on an application built with Symfony using Sonata Admin Bundle.

My problem is I just discovered a bug that seems to only affect desktop browsers.

I have a field that displays an image and the image colors are changed according to user selections.

This works fine on mobile right now and always worked (last checked a week ago) but for some reason stopped working on desktops.

**Works on:** iPhone (Safari and Chrome) & iPad (Safar and Chrome)

**Doesn't work:** Macbook (Safari and Chrome) & Microsoft (Chrome, Edge and FF)

Here is the code responsible for changing the colors in the images:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var logos = {};
        {% for image in images %}
            var image{{ image.id }} = '{{ image.content|raw }}';
            logos['logo-' + {{image.id}}] = image{{ image.id }};
        {% endfor %}
        $('.target').parent('div').append("<div id='image_preview'></div>");
        var container = $("#image_preview");
        {# apply selected colors to image preview #}
        function applyColors() {
            $('.defaul_image_color').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != 'FFFFFF') {
                    $('path.' + $(this).data('param')).css('fill', $(this).val())
                }
            })
        }
        {# display image and apply colors #}
        function displayImage() {
            if ($('.target option:selected').val()) {
                container.html(eval('image'+$('.target option:selected').val()));
                applyColors();
            } else {
                container.html('');
            }
        }
        displayImage();

        {# trigger on color or image change #}
        $('.defaul_image_color, .target').on('change', function () {
            displayImage();
        });

        $('#select2-results-5').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
           $('#select2-results-5 li .select2-result-label').each(function () {
               if (logos[$(this).text()] != undefined && !$(this).has('svg').length) {
                   $(this).prepend('<span class="svg_list">' + logos[$(this).text()] + '</span>');
               }
           })
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not trying to be lazy but I don't know where to start troubleshooting this problem so you can log into my test account to inspect the problem firsthand:

http://adminstage.3w1.website/admin/admin-customer-theme/167/edit
user: topsellerz1234@gmail.com
pw: 1234

The problem is with the rendering of the selected logo image.
Settings->Theme->edit theme->logo tab

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Possible typo: `.defaul_image_color` is missing a 't'.

Comment: @RoAchterberg this is on the TODO list of fixes but it's misspelled throughout our code so it's not the source of this problem.

Comment: Your identification of the problem sounds a little vague. What is your definition of 'desktops'? Which browsers specifically? Don't forget versions and OS variants. Have you tested the results on a live cross-browser platform such as BrowserStack?

Comment: @RoAchterberg You're right let me edit the question to add this. The problem was confirmed on Browserstack.

Comment: I'm confused. You say it "stopped working on desktops", but now you cite iPhone as the only platform that's showing the problem. Please clarify.

Comment: @RoAchterberg please check edits

Comment: Please update your question to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RoAchterberg I've included account login details. You may log in to inspect the code. This seems to be a js problem, you think?

Comment: "_I don't know where to start troubleshooting this problem_" - I gave you some pointers to at least make a first attempt yourself.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Thank you. I'll use what you suggest.

Comment: @RoAchterberg what are some reasons this js code would not work on desktops browsers but work on mobile? I’m trying to narrow this down a bit more.

Comment: @RoAchterberg the fix, hopefully not a hack, was to prepend the fill value with ‘#’

Comment: A hex-rgb value has [strict and well-defined syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color). The `fill` attribute follows the regular CSS color naming rules. Your update is most certainly not a hack, you merely fixed illegal syntax for a color value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case but try to use `rgb()` color format instead of hexa.

Comment: Thanks for answering and my solution was actually close to yours. The solution was to prepend the fill value with ‘#’. Not sure why it suddenly stopped working after many years. Maybe someone can explain this in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to fix this problem was prepending the fill value with ‘#’. I’m not sure why my code worked for years without it. If someone can explain why it stopped working and why it worked without it on mobile I’ll mark that as the answer.